# FragmentTransaction replace method not replacing a specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using TabLayout to show three tabs and on selection of each am calling FragmentTransaction.replace method. Now my problem is that the first two fragments are correctly replaced but the third fragment in particular is not getting replaced though I debugged and found that all corresponding methods of the 3rd fragments are called and there is no error. Now am out of my wits, please help!!.

This is the code in my onCreate() method of my main activity from where i am showing the three tabs.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Explore"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Me"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        HomeTabFragment htf = new HomeTabFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.tab_content_fragment, htf);
        transaction.commit();
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                if (position == 0) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    HomeTabFragment htf = new HomeTabFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.tab_content_fragment, htf);
                    //transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ItemListFragment ilf = new ItemListFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.tab_content_fragment, ilf);
                    //transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    MeTabFragment meTabFragment = new MeTabFragment();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.tab_content_fragment, meTabFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                    //transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my MeTabFragment...

```
public class MeTabFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
private DisplayDensity display;
private int profilePicSizeInPx;
private final float percentageOfScreenHeightOfProfilePic = 0.15f;
private CheckInternetConnection connection;
private ImageView userProfilePic;
private TextView userName;
private ProgressBar profilePicPB;
private String personPhotoUrl;
private String PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = "400";
private SharedPreferences sPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ListView m_homeOfferLV = null;
MeTabAdapter m_meTabAdapter = null;
ArrayList<MeData> m_ArrayList;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
// Creating a listener interface to communicate back to the calling activity
//OnLogOutButtonClickListener mCallback;
private Analytics analytics;
private Tracker t;
// Container Activity must implement this interface

public static MeTabFragment newInstance() {
    MeTabFragment fragment = new MeTabFragment();
    //fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    analytics = new Analytics(getActivity(),getActivity().getString(R.string.MeTabFragment));
    t = analytics.getTrackerInstance();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(Analytics.analytics_enabled && Analytics.lastTabStripPositionValue==2)
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sPrefs.edit();
    mGoogleApiClient = ApiClientGoogle.mApiClientGoogle;
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    connection = new CheckInternetConnection(getActivity());
    display = new DisplayDensity(getActivity());
    profilePicSizeInPx = (int) (percentageOfScreenHeightOfProfilePic * (float) display.getScreenHeightInPixels());
    //mAnalytics = new Analytics(getActivity(),"Me");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_me_tab, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    m_homeOfferLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.me_tab_list_view);
    userProfilePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name_tv);      
    userProfilePic.getLayoutParams().height = profilePicSizeInPx;
    userProfilePic.getLayoutParams().width = profilePicSizeInPx;
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("MeScreen")
            .setAction("click")
            .setLabel("Me")
            .build());*/

    userName.setText(sPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.user_name), "User Name"));
    personPhotoUrl = sPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.user_profile_pic_url), null);
    if (sPrefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.is_google_logged_in), false) && personPhotoUrl != null) {
        personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0, personPhotoUrl.length() - 2) + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;
    }
    //if user is connected to internet and has profile pic url then fetch the url and show his profile pic.
    if (personPhotoUrl != null && connection.isConnectedToInternet()) {
        //show progress bar till the image is fetched and don't show the profile pic for now.
        profilePicPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new LoadProfileImage(userProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);
    } else {
        //show default pic only and set progress bar visiblity to null.
        Log.v("Debug", "Profile pic url is null");
        profilePicPB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    m_ArrayList = new ArrayList<MeData>();
    MeData meData = new MeData();
    meData.mPageRank = 1;
    meData.mTitle = "My Collections";
    meData.mDetail = "";
    m_ArrayList.add(meData);

    meData = new MeData();
    meData.mPageRank = 2;
    meData.mTitle = "My Offers";
    meData.mDetail = "";
    m_ArrayList.add(meData);

    meData = new MeData();
    meData.mPageRank = 3;
    meData.mTitle = "My Store List";
    meData.mDetail = "";
    m_ArrayList.add(meData);

    meData = new MeData();
    meData.mPageRank = 4;
    meData.mTitle = "Settings";
    meData.mDetail="";
    m_ArrayList.add(meData);

    //adding an empty item in the list to draw the bottom border.
    meData = new MeData();
    meData.mPageRank = 5;
    meData.mTitle = "";
    meData.mDetail="";
    m_ArrayList.add(meData);

    m_meTabAdapter = new MeTabAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_me_tab_template, m_ArrayList);
    m_homeOfferLV.setAdapter(m_meTabAdapter);
    m_homeOfferLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (m_ArrayList.get(position).mPageRank == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyProductsActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            } else if (m_ArrayList.get(position).mPageRank == 2) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyOffersActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);

            } else if (m_ArrayList.get(position).mPageRank == 3) {
                if (connection.isConnectedToInternet()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyStoresActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.check_internet_connection_try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else if (m_ArrayList.get(position).mPageRank ==4){
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SettingsActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
    m_homeOfferLV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;

        }
    });
    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(m_homeOfferLV);

}

//***************************************
// GOOGLE CONNECTION METHODS
//***********************************
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        profilePicPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
}

public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, listView.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

***Edit:*** Included the 3rd fragment's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="top">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
            android:layout_width="400px"
            android:layout_height="400px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic_progress_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/me_tab_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: let me look at fragment's layout

Comment: @sberezin: i have included the fragment's layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is identical for every fragment look for the reason in the third fragment's layout.
First of all change root ScrollView parameters like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

I suppose original `android:layout_height="0dp"` isn't processed as you expect, so fragment is actually inflated and added but you just don't see it.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue, i figured it out but anyways thanks for the reply. Also i am confused as it was working fine earlier but now the setting of height to 0 value doesn't display, anyways it's all fine.